# How can I set indicator type for all my imageview in my project using Kingfisher?

Tags: swift, uiimageview, kingfisher

This is how I set the indicator type of an imageview

```
ivProfilePicture.kf.indicatorType = .activity
```

But how do I set this for each and every imageview throughout my project so that I don't have to set this in every view controllers?

Is there anyway I can do in appdelegate?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can create  `UIImageView  extension` and use it like that

> imageView.loadImage(YourURL)

or

> imageView.loadImage("YourStringURL")

```
 import UIKit
 import Kingfisher

 extension UIImageView{
    func loadImage(_ url : URL?) {
        self.kf.indicatorType = .activity
        self.kf.setImage(with: url)
    }

    func loadImage(_ url : String?) {
        guard let urlStr = url else {return}
        self.kf.setImage(with: URL.init(string: urlStr))
    }

}
```

Comment: sorry i have been on holiday for the past few days. I tested and it is working as I wanted. Thanks!